# Is there any equivalent of placeholder in Elm?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, placeholder, elm

Is it possible to write the function in the following way:

```
find_parts: String -> List String -> List String                                                                        
find_parts word parts =
  List.filter String.contains _ word parts
```

Instead of:

```
find_parts: String -> List String -> List String
find_parts word parts =
  List.filter (\part -> String.contains part word) parts
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is, it is not [documented](http://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax).

Alternative solution, if you just want to avoid the lambda syntax use the now-deprecated [flip](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Basics#flip) if you're using something earlier than 0.19:

```
find_parts: String -> List String -> List String
find_parts word parts =
  List.filter (flip String.contains word) parts
```

Comment: To be more concise, you can also avoid the `parts` param

Comment: @gabrielperales You mean `find_parts word = List.filter (flip String.contains word)`? Right, but that was not really the question, and I do not want to go overboard with point-free style :)

Comment: What now? `flip` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the lambda with function composition:

```
find_parts: String -> List String -> List String
find_parts word parts =
  (List.filter << flip String.contains) word parts
```

or even just :

```
find_parts: String -> List String -> List String
find_parts =
  List.filter << flip String.contains
```